# named click event binding javascript

Tags: javascript, events

Without jQuery (or any library), how do I "name" an event so that I can detach just that event later. For **example**, I have 3 click events on one element:

```
target1.addEventListener(click, callback1, false);
target1.addEventListener(click, callback2, false);
target1.addEventListener(click, callback3, false);
```

I want to unbind just callback2. I'm **NOT** concerned with fallbacks. I know this is easy, but I **CANNOT** find any material on this outside of jQuery (maybe I'm using the wrong verbiage, idk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your event listeners and then use them in:
    `element.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)`

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
var listener = function (event) {
  /* do something here */
};
div.addEventListener('click', listener, false);
div.removeEventListener('click', listener, false);
```

Why would you not use jQuery though?

The link below is the documentation + code samples: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeEventListener

Comment: size purposes: no reason to load jQuery for a few simple functions on mobile-only site. THANK YOU! Been so long since I've used "old-school" that I can't remember how basic things work.